# VB Application connects to server fine on my computer but not on any other computer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I am at my wits end. The application I built works perfectly on my system but not on anyone elses. It is very simple, on load it queries the user for a Batch number and then filters the data to show only items with that batch number in the datagridview.

Here's the code I wrote:

```vb
'*******************************************************************************************************************************
' When the form loads, the following code opens a inputbox that asks the user for a batch number. This number then gets used
' to filter the data before populating the DataGridView
'*******************************************************************************************************************************
Private Sub frmAQFilter_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.ElementDataset.qryAQFilterData)

    Dim blnX As Boolean = True
    Dim msg As Integer

    Do While blnX
        strBatch = ""
        strBatch = InputBox("Batch Number: ")

        If Len(strBatch) > 0 Then
            DataTable1BindingSource.Filter = String.Format("Batch = '" & strBatch & "'")
            If Not DataTable1BindingSource.Count > 0 Then
                msg = MsgBox("No records found with the batch number: " + strBatch + Chr(13) _
                             + "Do you wish to enter a different batch number", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
                If msg = vbNo Then
                    Me.Close()
                    blnX = False
                End If
            Else
                blnX = False
            End If
        Else
            Me.Close()
            blnX = False
        End If
    Loop
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
End Sub
```

I don't get any errors, it just doesn't populate the dataset. My first thought was that the connection string was bad. No problems there. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is Sql Server 2008 and the needed databases installed on others' machines as well??

Comment: The computers that I tested the application on all had SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 install. They also had the same server connections that I have.

Comment: Are you using the express version of SQL? I think that that version only allows local access and has network access disabled by default.

Comment: We are all using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but I should also add that the the vb project is saved on the same server that the database is housed on, yet I can only make it work from my computer.

Comment: Comment out all try statements surrounding db data retrievIng. I dont Think your error is in this code, i get the impression that alot of important code is left out.

Comment: what in the world is this: `String.Format("Batch = '" & strBatch & "'")` ? I think you missed the point of String.Format()

Answer (score 0):

disable firewall. Also try to set the network address of your SQL server in vb.net in order to use a single external SQL server for both clients. I think this will help us to know where to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your attempt to help me with this. It turns out that the problem wasn't my code. When Visual Studio was installed on my computer, it was installed incorrectly which caused it to produce corrupted 64bit builds instead of 32bit builds.  Very aggravating, but the problem is corrected.